# Error al hacer una busqueda web en mac

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache

tengo un problema, estoy en un MacBook Air y estoy intentando configurar una página web. Estoy sirviendo la página web en MAMP puerto 8888, dentro de la carpeta "htdocs" tengo muchas fotos que se usan en esa página, además del styles.css, el script.js, el archivo "buscar.php" y el index.html.
Dentro de la página tengo un cuadro de busqueda con este código:

```
      <div class="search-container">
    <form method="get" action="buscar.php">
      <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Buscar..." value="">
      <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Pues al escribir algo, apunta al archivo "buscar.php" que contiene este código:

```
<?php
// Obtener la cadena de búsqueda ingresada por el usuario
$searchQuery = $_GET['q'];

// Directorio donde se encuentran las páginas web relacionadas con la búsqueda
$webDirectory = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs';

// Buscar páginas web que contengan videos relacionados con la búsqueda
$webPages = glob($webDirectory . '/*' . $searchQuery . '*.html');

// Mostrar una lista de enlaces a las páginas web encontradas
echo '<html>';
echo '<head>';
echo '<title>Videos de ' . $searchQuery . '</title>';
echo '</head>';
echo '<body>';
echo '<h1>Videos de ' . $searchQuery . '</h1>';
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($webPages as $webPage) {
  echo '<li><a href="' . $webPage . '">' . basename($webPage, '.html') . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
echo '</body>';
echo '</html>';
?>
```

con este codigo, pretendo hacer una búsqueda y poder encontrar páginas html que estén en la carpeta "htdocs". El caso es, cuando hago una busqueda, digamos por ejemplo "kimetsu", efectivamente si sale el contenido, como se ve en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Imagen donde sale el archivo kimetsu]

Bueno pero al pulsarlo, no se porque, no sale el archivo, que repito que existe dentro de la carpeta, pero al pulsarlo, pone esto: [image: Imagen de Nod Found]

Si alguien me puede decir porque pasa esto se lo agradezco, un saludo

EDITADO: enseño los archivos de la carpeta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y será que estás armando enlaces de los enlaces a archivos .html y las imágenes tienen otra extensión?

Comment: @Alfabravo no te entiendo que quieres decir, a mi me dan igual las imagenes, lo que quiero es que al darle a kimetsu se abra el archivo kimetsu.html y no lo hace.

Comment: Podrias inspeccionar los elementos del dom para ver que esta imprimiendo en los anchor tag

Comment: Ah ok. Yo entendí mal. Podrías por favor mostrar los archivos que están ahí y quieres mostrar? El contenido de la carpeta. Y en la consola del navegador, cómo es la petición que falla

Comment: @Alfabravo claro, lo edito en nada 2 minutos y lo ves

Comment: @JulioGuerrero no te llego a entender, que necesitas que haga?